# Another Maven "package doesn't exist" from all dependencies of my father pom

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Here is the header of my super pom

```
<groupId>com.nao.lsb</groupId>
<artifactId>lsb-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0-RC2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

And here his son named lsb-core

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>lsb-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.nao.lsb</groupId>       
    <version>1.2.0-RC2-SNAPSHOT</version>       
</parent>
```

So the folder of my parent is just a pom. Also I forgot to tell you this project is in java!

The issue I have is when I want to install/compile. The dependencies from my superpom are in the effective pom of lsb-core. When I run "`mvn clean install`" I have loads of "cannot find symbol" "package does not exist". **This error happened on every package used which are declared in my superpom**

For example:

```
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/l.hugo/Desktop/Project/src/lsb-core/src/main/java/com/nao/lsb/core/settings/LSBUserAndClientSettingsConfigurationService.java:[8,41] package org.springframework.beans.factory does not exist
```

But spring-beans appears in my effective pom of lsb-core with the right groupId, artifactId and version.
If I add to "lsb-core/pom.xml" the dependency of spring-beans then I don't get any error. But then my superpom is useless.

**I might have misunderstood something.**

Those package which are in the dependencies scope of my father are also not shown when I use the command "`mvn dependency:resolve`" or "`mvn dependency:analyze`".

I hope this is clear enough, if you need more information I'll be here to answer as fast as possible

Edit: before the error

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Df1u.png)

Comment: I bet there are more logged information...and I would bet they are related to network issues...please add more logging output ...before the packaging failures are comming...

Comment: I just uploaded a picture of the logging output before the packaging failed on the main topic !

Comment: First do not add links to pictures better copy & paste the text into the question..furthermore it looks like you don't have spring dependencies in your pom file...?

Comment: Yeah, i'm sorry for the presentation, I was at work and I was using the debian subOs from windows 10. So when i copy paste the text is almost unreadable. About the dependency my super pom have spring dependencies, I'm downloading the src right now form work in order to show you !

Comment: Unfortunately their servers are off, i'll call them monday